# Can not convert from Notification.builder to Notification

Tags: android

im having problems with whole Notification and NotificationCompat Stories, im using API 11, and im trying to add Style() to my Notification, like this code:

```
  Notification noti = new Notification.Builder()
 .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
 .setContentText(subject)
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
 .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
 .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
     .addLine(str1)
     .addLine(str2)
     .setContentTitle("")
     .setSummaryText("+3 more"))
 .build();
```

this is extact code as the developer.android itself has suggested at the site, but when i paste that in my own codes, it says can not convert from Notification.builder to Notification. so i tried to use NotificationCompat but seems the method setStyle, is Undefined for NotificationCompat , or atleast mine says so, is there any way i can manage this? or is there any compability library supports Notification.setStyle() for API 11? thanks

Comment: "this is extact code as the developer.android itself has suggested at the site" -- not in the `Notification.Builder` documentation, where they correctly pass in a `Context` to the `Notification.Builder` constructor.

Comment: nah i meant in the NotificationComapt.InboxStyle, and the context, is not my point, my point is why i dont have such thing NotificationComapt.InboxStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) instead. You can call `setStyle()` no matter the project's API level (of course, if the device doesn't support styles, that part will be ignored).

Note: You're also missing the `Context` parameter in the Builder's constructor -- this is necessary both with the native `Notification.Builder` and `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

Comment: yes, as i said i tried that, but NotificationCompa.Builder doesnt have setStyle() method

Comment: Yes, it does. You must supply the `Compat` variants though (`NotificationCompat.InboxStyle` in your case).

Comment: dude, try it, i have latest v4 support lib, and i dont have such thing  NotificationCompat.InboxStyle

Comment: @user3694470 Are you sure? I've just tested it, and it works fine. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html

Comment: thats the kind of problem i hate, my SDK is up to date, i even tried with v13

Comment: @user3694470 setStyle() was added to NotificationCompat quite a while ago (rev 10). Are you sure you have the current jar in your project? (Even if you update the SDK, you could still have an older version there)

Comment: yes , i am using the support v4 jar from my sdk/extra/android/support, which is up to date. amazing isnt it...

Comment: well for some unknown reasons it got fixed by itself. god damn it, thanks alot mate

Comment: @user3694470 hah, oh well, i'm glad :)

Comment: actually the the problem was , i had v13 in my build path, but i had not checked it , so ithought it will not use it, then i noticed it is using that version instead the v4,so i removed it... thats all half day gone for this